# How to change change rendered gradient color to transparent

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, gradient

I have a fairly basic flat image, that is black with a radial gradient that fades to gray (originally purple, but I modified the saturation to try to make this easier). I need the image instead fade from the black to transparent, I cannot find any tutorials online on this. The strength of the transparency should be based on how dark the color is (ie. black remains black, dark gray becomes more transparent, and light gray or white is fully transparent).

First of all, is this posssible in CS6? Secondly, how can I accomplish this if it is :P

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select All (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>)
2. Copy (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>)
3. Add Mask (Button at the bottom of the layers panel)

[image: Gradient Layer (Add Mask)]

4. Select the Mask Channel (<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> the mask thumbnail)
5. Paste (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>)
6. Invert Mask (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>)
7. Click the layer thumbnail to deselect the mask channel.

[image: Mask Added]

You can do this directly with color gradients—copying and pasting to the mask channel will automatically convert to greyscale.

It's also worth noting you can adjust the mask channel using levels etc. when the mask is active if the level of transparency isn't to your liking.

Comment: Thanks, it's very close. Anyway I can fix it? There doesn't appear to be any black at all anymore.
Before: http://i.imgur.com/dXqh1ji.png
After: http://i.imgur.com/6jQWFx8.png

Comment: There isn't much contrast in the gradient, what you can do is adjust the levels or brightness/contrast of the mask channel (when you alt+click to edit the mask)

Comment: All you need to remember is black=transparent and white=opaque and adjust the mask accordingly

Comment: Thanks. I've played around with the settings on the mask for the past 30 min but no luck :( I'll try again later, either way this seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Select Layer with gradient, set the layer blending mode to Multiply

[image: layer blending mode options]

**What does Multiply do?**

> Looks at the color information in each channel and multiplies the base color by the blend color. The result color is always a darker color. Multiplying any color with black produces black. Multiplying any color with white leaves the color unchanged. When you’re painting with a color other than black or white, successive strokes with a painting tool produce progressively darker colors. The effect is similar to drawing on the image with multiple marking pens.

From the [Adobe Photoshop Help Files](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/blending-modes.html)

I suggest you read the rest of their help files to get an understanding of what each blending mode does.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It appears if I set the "blend if" to gray, nothing happens even with blend mode set to multiple, at least I assume that's what's meant by blend color.

Comment: What is "blend if"? Did you change the "Layer Blending Mode" option that is to the right of the opacity settings on the layer panel?

Comment: I right clicked the layer, blending options and set the options there.
http://i.imgur.com/dXqh1ji.png it's still black -> gray

Comment: @user2704766 Ohh sorry, my method only works if you have a layer underneath your gradient layer with a color. For your situation I would follow CAI's answer.